# How to use recursion in SCALA. java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: scala, recursion

So, when i try to count math exp, i've got an error :

> "Uncaught error from thread [DTsystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5]: null, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[DTsystem]
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError"

What could be the problem?

```
def counter(n:Seq[Int]):Seq[Int]={
//count differences
val x = n.sliding(2,1).toList.map(x=> (x(1)-x(0)).toDouble)
//count how many times occurs each element of the list
val y = x.groupBy(i=>i).map(i => (i._1, i._2.size.toDouble)).toList
//count math expectation  
val z = y.map(i=>(i._1, (i._2*1)/x.length))
val g = z.map(i=>i._1*i._2).sum.toInt
val fin = n.last+g
var arr = new ListBuffer[Int]()
arr+=fin
if (arr.last<100) counter(n)
else arr
}
```

Comment: `(arr.last<100)` must never be true, so the recursion never ends. You'll need to debug to find out why.

Comment: @Carcigenicate do you mean that `arr.last<100` will _always_ be true?

Comment: @JoelBerkeley Whoops, dur. Yes. Posted that while running out of the house. My bad.

Answer (score 3):

The above code says essentially:

```
def counter(n: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] = {
  val fin = someFunnyFunction(n)
  if (fin < 100) throw new StackOverflowError
  else ListBuffer(fin)
}
```

that is, whenever `fin` turns out to be less than `100`, your code says that the recursion should never terminate, and the program crashes with a `StackOverflowError`. For example, for `n = 1 to 10`, the above code goes into eternal recursion with `g = 1` and `fin = 11`.

Recursive calls of shape

```
def foo(x): Bar = {
  ...
  foo(x)
  ...
}
```

are *useless* in the *best* case, and actively harmful in all other cases.

Comment: as a side point, if this had been written tail recursive, what would happen? Would it just be an infinite loop?

Comment: @JoelBerkeley yup, `@tailrec` looks like an infinite loop. Doesn't terminate, doesn't crash.